# How to set font of all fields in a crystal report file non-programatically?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a couple of crystal report files and the fonts for all the fields are Arial and I want to change them to Times New Roman. I tried selecting all but when I do that I can't set the font.

Is there anyway to set all the fields in a report to a font from the UI?

Using Crystal Reports XI Release 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you select all fields then CR will disable all the options from the font toolbar. You can still change all the fields' fonts, though. Select all your reports objects *that have text* (this will NOT work if you select, say, a line object along with them). Then right-click the objects → "Format Objects" → "Font" tab.

All of the font options should be available there.

Answer (score 2):

[Ryan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16342490/) will not work with Crystal Reports 2008. You will need to upgrade to a newer version. I am using Crystal Reports 13.

Select All using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Unselect drawing objects like lines, boxes, etc. Right-click, you will get the option to format multiple objects. Choose your styles.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have one object designed the way you want you could use ´Format Painter´, similar to that from MS Word: right click -> Format Painter (copy style), then just click to another object and the style will be pasted.